# what does "to go" mean after a noun?

Tags: grammar, verbs

I met such a sentence:
*with two more years to go at St.Joe's*
Which here means **to go** after years.If the meaning is to keep learning, then why is the form just in the infinitive?I would be happy if someone explains this point

Comment: The speaker is not due to leave St. Joe's (is it a school?) for another two years.

Comment: @KateBunting so, to + inf after noun means *be due to*?

Comment: No, that is what _this particular sentence_ means. 'There are two more years to go' means 'of the period of time something is planned to last, two years remain.' So, if St. Joe's is a school, the speaker expects to be there for two more years.

Comment: @KateBunting thanks for yor help